# How to stylize td of inner and outer table without use of div tags?

Tags: html, css

My code looks as follows:

```css
.outer tr td {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /*red*/
}
.inner tr td {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  /*blue*/
}
.outer tr td:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25);
  /*green*/
}
```

```html
<table class="outer">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="inner">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="inner">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The main problem is that, the green color is shown when I hover my inner `table`'s `td`. The problem may not have arrived if I used normal `rgb()` or hexadecimal colors. I need the transparency on a purpose. Help me so that my inner `td` doesn't get green color on my hover.

I have class names for each `td` in each row. I'm using class names for an `ajax` operation using `jquery`. So, I could not change the class names. This is is not my actual table. If I'd have to apply `css` to all my `td`s using their class name it would make my clients' browser some time to load. Please help me with the `css` coding to ignore the styles of a parent. Or find me a way to stylize a `table` but not its children `table`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly...

The `inner` table is inside of `outer` table, this means that

```
.outer tr td:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25);
  /*green*/
}
```

is still valid when hovering over a `<td>` inside the `.inner`.  You will need to override the `.inner tr td:hover` as well to undo the color change done by `.outer tr td:hover`:

```
.inner tr td:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  /*blue*/
}
```

Comment: I think this will solve my problem. I have to override my outer table settings. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: left;
}

th{
    background: #3d3d3e;
    color:#fff;
}
```

FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/5fxku4wb/2/

Comment: I got my answer from Lochemage. This is not the answer I was looking for. Anyway, thank you for your offer, Manjunath Siddapppa...

Answer (score 0):

Although there's already an answer provided, I think you should be aware of CSS Cascades. Using [:not](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) you can exclude the inner class from inheriting the outer class CSS. Example:

```
.outer tr td:not(.inner):hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25);
    /*green*/
}
```

Comment: My clients will not be using browsers compatible with CSS3. So I prefer Lochemage's anwser. Thank your for your answer.